# Single.fromCallable#call never called

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm calling the following code from the activity, on the main thread, which executes some JavaScript in a webview, and then I call a method returning RxJava Single inside the callback.

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView webView, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(webView, url);

            webView.evaluateJavascript("someMethodCall()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String retVal) {
                    String input = f(retVal);

                    Timber.d(TAG, "BEFORE doSomethingAndReturnSingle");
                    // reachable until here
                    helperClass
                            .doSomethingAndReturnSingle(input)
                            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                            .doOnSuccess(new Action1<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(String aesKey) {
                                    Timber.d(TAG, "doOnSuccess");
                                }
                            })
                            .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                    Timber.e(TAG, "error", throwable);
                                }
                            });

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
```

The method returning `Single` is as follows:

```
public Single<String> doSomethingAndReturnSingle(String input) {
    // some operations on input
    // this is still reachable
    return Single.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String call() {
            // this is never called
            Timber.d(TAG, "fromCallable");
            return "test";
        }
    });
}
```

I put logs and breakpoints everywhere, but somehow I cannot get past the single: neither `doOnSuccess`, `doOnError` are ever called, even more: **the `call` method inside `Single.fromCallable` is never called either**!

What am I doing wrong?

I tried both debug run and normal run, I checked logs in logcat, and the `Single.fromCallable#call` never gets executed.

Comment: Where are you subscribing to the result?

Comment: you are missing the "subscribe" call

Comment: For future visitors: to avoid this kind of issue, it's better to not use `doOnSuccess` / `doOnError`, but put the callbacks in `subscribe` - that way it's impossible to forget to subscribe.